# Chazal and Rain Clouds

Tags: sources-mekorot, chazal

I was read in [*Torah Tavlin*](http://www.torahtavlin.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/37-Pinchos1.pdf) the following:

*"Chazal tell us that the darkest clouds contain the most rain."*

Does anyone know where the source for this *Chazal* is located?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ta'anis 10a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=10&format=text):

> דכי אתא רב דימי אמר אמרי במערבא נהור ענני זעירין מוהי חשוך ענני סגיין מוהי

Translation:

> As when Rav Dimi came [to Bavel from Israel], he said: "They say in the West [i.e. the Land of Israel], 'Light clouds, little water. Dark clouds, abundant water.'"

This follows a statement that R' Y'hoshua' understands this concept to be implied by the parallel verses [II *Sh'mu'el* 22:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08b22.htm#12) and [*T'hillim* 18:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2618.htm#12).